# facebook session with multiple users

Tags: paw-app

In Paw App, I've managed to retrieve a Facebook OAuth token as described in the [documentation](https://paw.cloud/docs/examples/facebook-api) but I can't find how to login with another Facebook user.

I had to enter my Facebook credentials the first time I retrieved the access token, and now it doesn't request it anymore. The sessions are empty (created a new one and deleted the default one).

Any suggestion?

Comment: If your authorization mechanism is based on sessions (not on OAuth tokens), then you can use the Sessions you can see on the top left corner next to the environments button. Each session holds a set of cookies, that will be used and written to on "Set-Cookie" headers from responses. If you switch the session, you'll have a fresh new cookie container. That's how you can handle multiple "user sessions" / "user accounts" when based on cookies.